# Calling a method of a Test Class from another Test class

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit to unit test my application (using Zend Framework 2). I am stuck in a situation where I need to call a method that is in one test class
from another test class. Let me explain myself with a small example:

```
<?php
// TestUser.php
namespace Test\User;

class UserTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public static function GetUserCount(){

        // some code here

    }

}

?>

<?php
// TestAdmin.php
namespace Test\Admin;

use Test\User;

class AdminTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public static function AdminAction(){

        Test\User::GetUserCount();

    }

}

?>
```

When I call the `Test\User::GetUserCount();` or `User::GetUserCount();` I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Test\User' not found in path/to/TestAdmin.php
>   on line 11

Any idea if the method is callable from one test class to another test class? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: The class name is: UserTest not User

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would Mock the other class call, to ensure the returned values are what your class is expecting.  You may also link some test together with [Test Dependencies](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies).

I have added a short sample.  Note, I assume you added the AdminAction and GetUserCount() as samples since these are not really test methods that you would have with PHPUnit tests.

TestUser.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\User;

class UserTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $UserObject;
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->UserObject = new Test\User();    // Normal Object
    }

    public static function testGetUserCount()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->UserObject->GetUserCount(), 'Testing the basic object will return 1 if initialized');  // Do your tests here.
    }
}
```

TestAdmin.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Admin;

class AdminTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $AdminObject;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->AdminObject = new Test\Admin();
    }

    public static function testAdminAction()
    {
        // Create a stub for the User class.
        $stub = $this->getMock('User');

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('GetUserCount')
             ->will($this->returnValue(2));

        // Calling $stub->GetUserCount() will now return 2.  You can then ensure the Admin class works correctly, by changing what the mocks return.
        $this->assertEquals(2, $stub->GetUserCount());
    }

}
```